# Implementing a database structure for generic objects

Tags: mysql, database-design, nosql

I'm building a PHP/MySQL website and I'm currently working on my database design. I do have some database and MySQL experience, but I've never structured a database from scratch for a real world application which hopefully is going to get some good traffic, so I'd love to hear advices from people who've already done it, in order to avoid common mistakes. I hope my explanations are not too confusing.

**What I need**

In my application, the user should be able to write a post (title + text), then create an "object" (which can be anything, like a video, or a song, etc.) and attach it to the post. The site has a list of predefined object types the user can create, and I should be able to add new types in the future. The user should also have the ability to see the object's details in a dedicated page and add a comment to it - the same applies to posts.

**What I tried**

I created an `objects` table with these fields: `oid`, `type`, `name` and `date`. This table contains records for anything the user should be able to add comments to (i.e. posts and objects). Then I created a `postmeta` table which contains additional post data (such as text, author, last edit date, etc.), a `videometa` table for data about the "video" object (URL, description, etc.), and so on. A `postobject` table (`pid`,`oid`) links objects to posts. Additionally, there's a `comments` table which contains the comment text, the author and the ID of the object it refers to.

Since the list of object types is predefined and is probably not going to change (though I still need the ability to add a type easily at any time without changing the app's code structure or the database design), and it is relatively small, it's not a problem to create a "meta" table for each type and make a corresponding PHP class in my application to handle it.

Finally, a page on the site needs to show a list of all the posts including the objects attached to it, sorted by date. So I get all the records from the `objects` table with type "post" and join it with `postmeta` to get the post metadata. Then I query `postobject` to get all the objects attached to this post, and `comments` to get all the comments.

**The questions**

Does this make any sense? Is it any good to design a database in this way for a real world site? I need to join quite a few tables to get all the data I need, and the `objects` table is going to become huge since it contains almost every item (only the type, name and creation date, though) - this is to keep the database and the app code flexible, but does it work in the real world, or is it too expensive in the long term? Am I thinking about it in the wrong way with this kind of OOP approach?

More specifically: suppose I need to list all the posts, including their attached objects and metadata. I would need to join these tables, at least: `posts`, `postmeta`, `postobject` and `{$objecttype}meta` (not to mention an `users` table to get all posts by a specific user, for example). Would I get poor performance doing this, even if I'm using only numeric indexes?

Also, I considered using a NoSQL database (MongoDB) for this project (thanks to Stuart Ellis advice). Apparently it seems much more suitable since I need some flexibility here. But my doubt is: metadata for my objects includes a lot of references to other records in the database. So how would I avoid data duplication if I can't use `JOIN`? Should I use DBRef and the techniques described [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+References)? How do they compare to MySQL `JOIN`s used in the structure described above in terms of performance?

I hope these questions do make any sense. This is my first project of this kind and I just want to avoid to make huge mistakes before I launch it and find out I need to rework the design completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a NoSQL person, but I wonder whether this particular case might actually be handled best with a document database (MongoDB or CouchDB). Various type of objects with metadata attached sounds like the kind of scenario that MongoDB is designed for.

FWIW, you've got a couple of issues with your table and field naming that might bite you later. For example, type and date are rather generic, and also reserved words. You've also mixed singular and plural table names, which will throw any automatic object mapping.

Whichever database you use, it's a good idea to find an existing set of database naming conventions and apply it from the start - this will help you avoid subtle issues and ensure that your naming stays consistent. I tend to use the Rails naming conventions ATM, because they are well-known and fairly sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could store the object contents as a file, outside of the database, if you're concerned about the database space.

If you store anything in the database, you already have the object type in `objects`; so you could just add `object_contents` table with a long binary field to store the object. You don't need to create a new table for each new type.

Comment: I should clarify that I don't really have to store an actual video or a song file, instead the metadata would only consist of strings and ints - that's why a table with this extra data sounded more natural to me.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a lot of JOIN's in real world web application (5 to 10). Objects table may get large, but that's indices are for. So far, I don't see anything wrong in your database. BTW, what felt strange to me - one post, one object, and separate comments for each? No ability to mix pictures with text?